# what happens to TCP Connection if wrong ACK is received?

Tags: networking, wireshark, tcp

I have a server-client TCP connection. Server is sending data to client and clients acknowledges.

Server sends a packet with seq number 30326 and 1448 bytes of data in it. Client acknowledges it with ACK number 31730 instead of 31774 (30326+1448). I see in wireshark that after this wrong ACK is received there is no more transmission from server for this client.

Can anyone please comment on why server stop the transmission and what possibly could be the reason for this ACK. Is it wrong or an expected behavior from TCP.

Regards,

Comment: why you think sequence should be `31774`, sequence number is generated on both side, the client only needs to copy the seq no to ack number with increment of 1

Comment: @piyushj That's not correct. The ACK should contain the sequence number of the last byte received, as numbered by the sender.

Comment: @EJP true, I mistook the last byte received, as i was looking at SYN packet, but alas i can't edit my comment as its too late

Comment: Is it possible that a client receives 1400 bytes packet and acknowledges only 1000 bytes?
I don't think it can happen.

Comment: Could you give us a capture of the trafic?